# Is it possible to generate promo codes for in app purchases?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I have a free app with one in app purchase option, and I'd like to offer that IAP for free to some helpful users. In iTunes Connect it appears I can generate promo codes but those codes appear to be for the app itself (which, again, is free so I don't get it.)

Google searching brings up all sorts of claims that Apple doesn't allow you to create promo codes for in app purchases, but those threads are a couple of years old now. Can promo codes be created for IAP or is it just for apps themselves?

Comment: Couldn't you try and 'hard code it' yourself. I mean create a text input box that takes in a promo code and if code matches what you have stored then do everything that the in app purchase would've done.

Comment: Yes that's true. Ideally each developer wouldn't have to implement that on each app, but it is a good workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [possible](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10282016a) since October 28, 2016, see [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html).

[image: iTunes Connect screenshot]