# Generate redemption code programatically - Apple Volume Purchase Plan

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, volume-purchase-program

I have an enterprise application which will be distributed using Volume Purchase Plan. I've read the documentation and understand the method of generating and downloading the codes in a spreadsheet and sharing to users.

I want to automate this process from a Java application. Does Apple provide any API to query for the redemption codes using a valid VPP-enabled Apple account. I was going through the forum and found [generate promo codes for in app purchases](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230789/is-it-possible-to-generate-promo-codes-for-in-app-purchases) thread but couldn't find the solution with the accepted answer. Also followed the suggested methods in these Apple documents [App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/), [App Store Connect](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store-connect/), [Private Distribution](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev275598f16) and [business it](https://www.apple.com/business/it/) but couldn't get clear information on implementing in Java application.

Comment: Have you tried asking Apple?

Comment: Not yet. Checking if I could get some approach / solution from this community.